# ubuntu 13.04 wont start [sdb] asking for cache data failed

Tags: kernel, 64-bit, 13.04

i installed ubuntu 13.04 yesterday on my Acer Aspire 5742 and it all worked ok, i go to turn it on today, and just as it loads the log in screen a black screen that says
[58.620634] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[58.620708] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
i am unable to do anything with this up apart from turn the laptop off, it just repeats the message with different numbers at the start
This also occurred once whilst i was using google chrome, do not remember what i was doing at the time

i am completely new to linux and ubuntu and have no idea what this means
my laptop has 
intel i3
4gb ram
128 gb kingston hyperx SSD
running ubuntu 13.04 AMD64

EDIT: i had an empty sd card in the sd card reader, removed this and it seems to have stopped it, no idea if this is permanent or luck, can somebody please tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

This seems it is your SD card causing trouble! Just remove it every time you boot.

The message 'Asking for cache data failed' is because SD card, pendrives, etc. does not have a small amount of RAM cache (cache data) common to hard disks (HD). When kernel tries to enable such RAM for your SD card (thinking your SD card is a HD), this error appears. This is part of the process of the kernel probing hardware; totally normal.

Comment: What's not normal is that the boot is failing. Maybe the inserted card changes the names of the drives so that something got utterly confused...